# Is there a way to apply font-family to HTML Unicodes symbold like Degree celsius?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I want to know if there is a way to apply font family for HTML Unicode symbols. I am using degree celsius in html as ℃ and also tried placing in css as \2103. Currently the degree and C has a default font. But, I want to change the font to my required font-family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `span` around that character to which you apply a class that has a `font-family` definition according to the desired font.

```css
p {
font-size: 36px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.x {
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>The temperature is 28°C right now.</p>
<p>The temperature is 28<span class="x">°</span>C right now.</p>
```